# PARSE_ERROR MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

These lines give me the parse error, ı checked my syntax many times but it seems alright to me. I don't understand why does it give this error

code:

```
INSERT INTO club_request(RequestID,"Besiktas")
    SELECT RequestID
    FROM Request
    WHERE RequestName = "New goalkeeper";
```

error:

ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Besiktas") SELECT RequestID FROM Request WHERE RequestName = "New goalkeeper"' at line 1

Comment: Let's see.  You have use double quotes for both strings and identifiers -- that confuses me, even if not the SQL compiler.  You claim to be inserting two columns, but only provide one value.

Comment: I want to insert "Besiktas" string into second column, can't I use RequestID value and a string I take as an input and insert both ? Doesn't "Besiktas" count as a value in here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO club_request(RequestID, ClubName)
SELECT RequestID, ClubName
FROM Request, Club
WHERE RequestName = "New goalkeeper" AND ClubName = "Besiktas";
```

lately I have turned it into this and now it works as I wanted, can't we insert partial value from select clause and partial value as a string ?

Comment: no you can't you need as many columns even empty ones as there are columns in the table.